# How do I unpublish an elm package?

Tags: package, elm

Is there any way to unpublish my old elm package and publish a new one?

I could not find any way or command for that.

Answer (score 2):

Package registries usually don't allow you to do that (unrestricted) because it will break the build of everything that depends on it. See the so-called [left-pad controversy](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141577284765/kik-left-pad-and-npm) for an example of what happens when you do allow that.

Answer (score -1):

Elm packages are published in a package catalog. There are two ways to unpublish a package from the package catalog:

1. Delete it from your code and regenerate.
2. Upload an Elm box version with a different name that is not publishable.

Over time, the generated file names will eventually be replaced with the new, unpublished versions of the package.

Comment: This reads like it was generated through AI